# PostGIS ST_ApproximateMedialAxis producing odd results

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.4

I attempt to get the centre line from a simple polygon (centre line is ambiguous; but I need a line through the centre of the polygon whatever the shape: the shape is always a long buffered line parallel to a road):

[image]

Zoomed closer
[image]

Using the following overcomplicated SELECT to ensure that it is a not a MultiPolygon, is simple and conventional:

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_Boundary((ST_Dump(geom)).geom)) FROM table
```

When I attempt to get the approximate centre line using the following I get a "broken" MultiLineString:

```
SELECT 
  ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(
      ST_MakePolygon(ST_Boundary((ST_Dump(st_intersection)).geom))
  ) AS geom FROM table
```

[image]

Zoomed In:
[image]

My pretty large function works for 99% of a pretty large and complicated national extent however I keep getting these rare broken cases that are really confusing me. The bug in my function definitely sits with this action.

Is there is a more appropriate way to get a good approximate centre line of a polygon?

Comment: Can you share the broken polygon as text? `st_astext(geom)`